# Anker USB-C to HDMI dongle 4k@60hz

Tags: display, display-resolution, surface

I bought an Anker USB-C to HDMI dongle that [supports 4k@60hz](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07THJGZ9Z).  However I have only been ever able to coax 4k@30hz out of it from my Surface Laptop 3, both from the onboard USB-C port as well as either video-enabled USB-C port on the Surface Dock 2 (which also [supports 4k60](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/d/surface-dock-2/8qd908364sg2?activetab=pivot:techspecstab#tab1a15db143-87da-4b99-8662-8206285e183d)).  Given that both devices supposedly support it, I'm leaning towards it being a driver issue in [`linux-surface`](https://github.com/linux-surface/linux-surface)

I noticed this `dmesg` output after moving the cable between ports shows it as USB 2.0, regardless of which port I'm using.  Might this be the reason why?  If so, how can I force it to use USB 3.0?

```
[  730.426997] usb 3-1.1.4: new full-speed USB device number 13 using xhci_hcd
[  730.554587] usb 3-1.1.4: not running at top speed; connect to a high speed hub
[  730.557622] usb 3-1.1.4: New USB device found, idVendor=2109, idProduct=0103, bcdDevice= 6.12
[  730.557630] usb 3-1.1.4: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[  730.557633] usb 3-1.1.4: Product: USB 2.0 BILLBOARD
[  730.557635] usb 3-1.1.4: Manufacturer: VLI Inc.
[  730.557637] usb 3-1.1.4: SerialNumber: 0000000000000001
```

Comment: The obvious question is: Does the monitor supports 4K@60Hz over its HDMI input? Many only support it over DisplayPort so it's worth checking.

Comment: That's a good question, and I'm not entirely sure.  It's a [Samsung 40" TV](https://www.samsung.com/us/televisions-home-theater/tvs/full-hd-tvs/40-class-mu6290-4k-uhd-tv-un40mu6290fxza/).  [This site](https://www.displayspecifications.com/en/model/a035f4f) lists it as 50/60Hz vertical refresh with HDMI2.0.